# CAML query on special characters

Tags: development, caml

I am trying to get a specific item from sharepoint list, representing the username of the current logged in user. The list has a column called UserName, which has values like:     i:0#.f|sql_membership|Jacky

I am building a CAML query in C#, to get the row where current logged in user = that column. My code looks like this:

```
  SPUser user = web.CurrentUser;
  string userName = user.LoginName;
  query.Query = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><Field Name= 'UserName'/><Value Type='Text'>" + userName + "</Value></Eq></Where></View></Query>";
   SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);
   SPListItem item = items[0];
```

The problem, is that it brings the first row with ID =1, which has the value of: i:0#.f|sql_membership|Edward while it should bring: i:0#.f|sql_membership|Jacky according to the value the userName variable which has my username

How do I solve this?

Comment: try removing the view and query nodes from the caml xml

Comment: @Jaime , now it stopped bringing any items at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
query.Query = @"<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='UserName' /><Value Type='Integer'><UserID Type='Integer' /></Value></Eq></Where>";
SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);
if (items.Count > 0)
{
    SPListItem item = items[0];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to escape the special characters in XML. So you need to pass the value under CDATA object. Something like:

```
<Contains><FieldRef Name='Title' /><Value Type='Text'><![CDATA[{0}]]>  </Value</Contains>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use following Query:

```
<Where>
  <Eq>
    <FieldRef Name="UserName" />
    <Value Type="Integer">
      <UserID />
    </Value>
  </Eq>
</Where>
```

So

```
query.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='UserName' /><Value Type='Integer'><UserID /></Value></Eq></Where>";
```

`<UserID />` will get the current user ID.

The following will also work:

```
var currentUserId = web.CurrentUser.ID;
query.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='UserName' LookupId='True' /><Value Type='Lookup'>" + currentUserId + "</Value></Eq></Where>";
```

Comment: Hi Arsalan. How will UserID check for i:0#.f|sql_membership|Jacky  ?????

Comment: It's still modifying i:0#.f|sql_membership|Edward instead of my username.

Comment: Do you always need current login user or other user than logged in user ?

Comment: @MonicaJagani I need the logged in user always

Comment: Above mentioned solution should work of taking the web.CurrentUser.ID and passing to CAML query.

Comment: What do you get in `SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName` ?